# OpenCV(Android) - remove contours drawn

Tags: android, opencv, java-threads

The apps detect the specific color on the frame and draw the contours using OpenCV. And when the capture button is clicked, the frame image will be used to do some image processing, while the contours drawn is also been captured with the frame which is not what I want it to.
My question is how can I remove the contours drawn when I click the capture button. Or is there any method to get the frame without contours drawn?

The method I have tried:

1. Lock the onCapture() until onCameraFrame is called and return mRbg
   before drawContour() is called.
2. Clone mRgba to new Mat and use the new Mat as parameter of subColor

But both of them didn't work.

I'm thinking to pause onCapture() until onCameraFrame called and done several times skipping the lines of drawing contours to make sure nothing has drawn on the frame. But I don't know how to handle two synchronized().

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    lock = true;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //do something
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //do something
        //↓to make sure onCameraFrame is pause before the finger left the screen
        lock = false;
        synchronized (locker) { locker.notify(); }
    }

    return true;
} 

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    //Pause until onTouch() is done
    commandLocker();

    //Detect the contour
    mDetector.setHsvColor(txtHsv);
    if (area) {
        nRgba = mRgba.submat(ey, sy, sx, ex);
        mDetector.process(nRgba);
    } else {
        mDetector.process(mRgba);
    }

    //Skip this when onCapture is called
    //Draw the contour on the frame
    if (!capture) {
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
        if (nRgba != null && area) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(sx, sy), new Point(ex, ey), areaColor, 3);
            Imgproc.drawContours(nRgba, contours, -1, contourColor);
        } else
            Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, contourColor);
    }

    return mRgba;
}

public void onCapture(View view) throws IOException {
    capture = true;
    //Pause until onCameraFrame() done
    if (!area)
        subColor(mRgba);
    else
        subColor(nRgba);
}

public void subColor (Mat src) throws IOException {
    //do something
}

private void commandLocker() {
    synchronized (locker) {
        while (lock) {
            try {
                locker.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "InterruptedException");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Frame captured without processing]
[image: Processed image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)` function, if the condition:

`if (nRgba != null)`

is not satisfied, you overwrite your original mat `mRgba` by doing `Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, contourColor);`

Is that your problem?

Comment: if the area is selected by the user, nRgba (submat of mRgba) is not null, then will do Imgproc.drawContours(nRgba, contours, -1, contourColor), else do Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, contourColor). This has no problems in drawing the contours. The problem is the image captured includes the contours border drawn by this method, which is not what I want. What I want is the contours show on the screen but not on the image saved.

Comment: I don't understand this part: "The problem is the image captured includes the contours border drawn by this method". Do you mean that the image captured already has the contours drawn before you calling the **Imgproc.drawContours**?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. The image captured is from the Mat nRgba/mRgba, which has the contours drawn. I want to do onCameraFrame() several times when onCapture() is called but skip the lines of Imgproc.drawContours() so that no contours is drawn on the new frames in order to make sure nRgba/mRgba used in subColor() is the Mat without contours drawn.

Comment: Oh I see. If I understood correctly, why don't you declare a global Boolean variable (i.e. **needCountors**) with the default value false. Each time onCapture() is called, you set the value to true. Then onCameraFrame will be called several times and you test **needCountors**. If set to true, then you need to draw the contours, and set **needCountors** to false. The next calls to onCameraFrame won't draw the contours since its set to false. In the next onCapture, you reset the **needCountors** to true and repeat the process.